# Questions about PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats

I've been searching in the pgfplots manual pdf for a few things for the past 30 minutes, but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. I assume it's basic but here it goes:

How do I plot coordinates without connecting them through lines?
and
How would I go about plotting a linear regression for those coordinates? I've calculated the equation for the lin.reg. outside pgfplots, I just can't seem to grasp how to plot the graph...

Thanks in advance.
Here's where I'm at thus far:

```
\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    separate axis lines,
    xlabel={xlabel},
    ylabel={ylabel},
    xmin=0, xmax=20,
    ymin=1.35, ymax=1.85,
    xtick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20},
    ytick={1.40,1.50,1.6,1.7,1.8},
    legend pos= south east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,]

    \addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=o,]
    table {
0   1.45
1   1.48
2   1.5
3   1.53
4   1.59
5   1.62
6   1.75
7   1.81};

\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=x,]
    table {
0   1.45
1   1.44
2   1.44
3   1.44
4   1.44
5   1.44
6   1.43
7   1.43
8   1.44
9   1.43
10  1.44
11  1.45
12  1.45
13  1.46
14  1.46
15  1.47
16  1.48
17  1.49
18  1.49
19  1.5
20  1.5};

\legend{s/ óleo, c/ óleo}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig:cargacorrente}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `only marks` in the `\addplot` command will remove the lines between data points; to plot a straight line do something like

```
\addplot [red, thick, domain=0:20] {1.4 + 0.06*x};
```

PS Next time, please post a compilable snippet, with all the necessary packages, and try to reduce the example to the minimal size that shows your problem.